# Reading .wav as bytes

Tags: python, wav, wave, soundfile

I'm reading .wav file in Python with 2 tools. First - with module `soundfile`:

```
wav = sf.read(speech_file)
b = io.BytesIO(wav[0])
```

In result I get such bytes data. It's correct:

```
....\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ .....
```

Then I read .wav with module `wave`:

```
wf = wave.open(speech_file, "rb")
data = wf.readframes(wf.getparams().nframes)
```

The result bytes are totally incorrect:

```
....a\x00\xda\x00\xcb\x00\xba\x00\xb0\x00\xa3\x00\x8f\x00|\x00g\x00S\x00=\x00&\x00\x0b\x00\xf3\xff\xd4\xff\xb0\xff\x8d\xffe\xff\xff\x18\xff\xef\xfe\xc6\xfe\x99\xfed\xfe-\xfe\xf5\xfd\xc0\xfd\x92\xfdj....
```

Why did not two different tools give the same result? How to make a second byte object from the first one? In fact, I can't use `wave`'s bytes as it is totally different from original soundtrack.

Comment: Why do you think the first result is correct?  A WAVE file starts out with a known header.. 
 The first few bytes are the characters "RIFF".  I don't see that.  The `wave` module skips over the header and returns the data, and that data looks far more like 16-bit PCM data.  In the real world, you'll never get a long sequence of 0s.  There's always background noise.

Comment: I converted bytes into numpy array and then visualised it. The first tool give real sound signal http://timg.in/BFlNn

Comment: You're aware that the samples are 16-bit values, not bytes?

Comment: Really, there's not much we can do without seeing the code nor access to the file.  The `wave` module works very well; I've used it many times.

Comment: Loaded .wav and bytes data to the [drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YwHXeU4LSv0sn-dia5dKXbiRq83tZR6O?usp=sharing). Hope it will help solve the issue. Original .wav soundtrack is russian speech. All code I have loaded above

Comment: Yes, original data is 16-bit values. In my pipeline i need to use bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in module `wave` reads .wav files in DSD format, soundtrack is represented as sequence of 0 and 1. However, `soundfile` reads .wav in PCM format, which is array of signal's amplitude values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).